# Header and Footer to take full width of page when content overflows

Tags: html, css, responsive

Example - https://codepen.io/Rhinoo/pen/GRKBVQJ

```
<html>  
  <body>
    <style>
      header {
         background:navy; 
         color:white; 
         padding:10px; 
         margin-bottom:50px
      }
      footer {
         background:silver; 
         padding:10px;
         margin-top: 50px;
      }      
    </style>

    <div>      

      <header>
        Some toolbar here that should be 100% width | Links | And stuff
      </header>

      <div class="content">
         <p style="white-space: nowrap;">
           Content here thats very long and doesn't break so overflow width... quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog .........
      </p>

    </div>

    <footer>
      Typical footer info here (c) Someone at sometime...
    </footer>

    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

When the browser is resized to be narrower than the table (so the content overflows) horizontal scroll bars appear - BUT the header/footer will not take up the full width.

[image: Example showing header doesn't take up 100% of page width if content overflows]

Using CSS/HTML only how do I make the header/footer take up the full width regardless if content overflows or not?

Comment: Please put **all** of the code here.  That includes the CSS, not just the HTML.  Linking to a codepen is not enough.

Comment: Why would that be? Its the PERFECT playground for this sort of thing? (online editor, immediate review of results, others modify and save etc)

Comment: @Ryan I'm suprised a seasoned user would even ask such a thing: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Comment: @Ryan I'm not trying to be aggressive or condescending.  The CSS for this question is key to answering it.  Not including it in the question itself makes this question depend on a 3rd party site to be answerable.  Please read this blog post: [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  It details a lot of the issues that have been run into with respect to web oriented domain questions and steps SO has taken to alleviate them.

Comment: @zero298 - cheers, makes sense and I had not seen the runnable webdev thing before on SO which does inline what I was using codepen for (web development not my usual thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    dispaly: table;
}
```

Example:

```css
header {
  background:navy; 
  color:white; 
  padding:10px; 
  margin-bottom:50px
}
footer {
  background:silver; 
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table {white-space: nowrap;}

body {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      
    <header>
      Some toolbar here | Links | And stuff
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content here</p>
      
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Some big table here</th>
          <td>Going on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
        </td>
      <table>
        <p>Looks fine normally, but if you make window smaller than width of table so horizontal scrollbars appear, then scroll right the header/footer are not full width
    </div>
    <footer>
      Typical footer info here (c) Someone at sometime...
    </footer>
    
      </div>
```

Comment: Fixes problem but introduces another - stops header/footer div taking up full width when content is narrower than full screen - run code snippet in expanded window and you will see.

Comment: Afraid not - header/footer div no longer take up full width if browser is wider than content if you use display:table or display:inline-flex https://codepen.io/Rhinoo/pen/OJLoJPo

Comment: `body {  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The text inside the table doesn't break because you added `white-space: nowrap;` to it. Remove it and it'll work. If you still want to keep it then consider adding a div around the table with `overflow-x: auto;` it doesn't break the layout on smaller sizes.

```css
header {
  background:navy; 
  color:white; 
  padding:10px; 
  margin-bottom:50px
}
footer {
  background:silver; 
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table {white-space: nowrap;}

.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      
    <header>
      Some toolbar here | Links | And stuff
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content here</p>
      
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Some big table here</th>
          <td>Going on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
          <td>and on and on and on</td>
        </td>
      </table>
      </div>
        <p>Looks fine normally, but if you make window smaller than width of table so horizontal scrollbars appear, then scroll right the header/footer are not full width
    </div>
    <footer>
      Typical footer info here (c) Someone at sometime...
    </footer>
    
      </div>
```

Comment: The nowrap is just to quickly illustrate what happens when the content overflows. (in real life there are a few large tables and some users with small mobile browsers).

Comment: You can either relayout your tables to fit on mobile or you make them horizontally scrollable with overflow-x: auto; Added an example to my answer.

Comment: overflow-x on table parent doesn't work very well. On desktop its fugly because scroll bar is at bottom of a table rather than at edge of window where users expect (in this case its a very long table). On mobile it stops the pinch resize working and its very hand to 'zoom out' to see more of the table. Every time I stumble across CSS it seems that what should be easy things are a complex, convoluted spaghetti mess of mystery and misery...